# Div box heights

Tags: html, height, alignment

Another CSS question.

I have div boxes within `<li>` tags, within a `<ul>` tag. The div tags each contain an image, with text under the image. The images are all the same size, however the length of the text isn't the same - so the div boxes aren't all the same size. I want the top of the images to align, but right now they look more like stairs. I tried changing the height of the divs, but that extends the box downward, rather than upward. Here's the corresponding code that I have so far.

```
<ul>
        <li class="line2"><div style="width:284px;border:3px;border-style:solid;"><img class="border" src="/images/icons/1.png" width="284" height="164" alt=""/><p>Paragraph.</p></div></li>
        <li class="line2"><div style="width:284px;border:3px;border-style:solid;"><img class="border" src="/images/icons/2.png" width="284" height="164" alt=""/><p>Longer Paragraph</p></div></li>
        <li class="line2"><div style="width:284px;border:3px;border-style:solid;"><img class="border" src="/images/icons/3.png" width="284" height="164" alt=""/><p>Longest Paragraph</p></div></li>
        </ul>
```

(The border is just so I can see what I'm working with)

I realize I could separate the image and text into different divs, but I have so many different divs already, I feel I'm being a bit excessive. If this is the best way to do it, I will, however I'd like to know for sure.

If anyone could help with this, I'd really appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: A screenshot would be nice. For now, I would say, `float: left` could do the job.

Answer (score 0):

A `<div>` tag basically adds a logically division with a line break. And that's why it is shown like stairs. So i suggest, you should try `<span>` tag instead, through which you can align your boxes horizentally;
I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything except the most obvious thing; I added `<br/>` tags under the text for the ones that were lower than the highest one. I know there's probably a better way to do this, but whatever is easiest works for me.